# Calculate a value over several rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I'm trying to update a column based on values from previous rows. My data looks like this:

```
InvID   InvAmnt PayAmnt orderId
1       10,00   100,00  1
2       20,00   100,00  2
3       30,00   100,00  3
4       40,00   100,00  4
```

What I want to do is update the table, so that the value of `InvAmnt` is subtracted from `PayAmnt`. But previous rows need to be considered, too. This would mean, in the first row I just subtract 10 from 100 and have a resulting 90. In the second row I subtract 20 from 90 (which was the result in the first row) and get 70 as a result, and so on. The desired output is like so:

```
InvID   InvAmnt PayAmnt orderId
1       10,00   90,00   1
2       20,00   70,00   2
3       30,00   40,00   3
4       40,00   0,00    4
```

I tried to do it with the window function `LAG` like this:

```
select ID, InvID, InvAmnt
,LAG(PayAmnt - InvAmnt,1,PayAmnt) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY OrderId) - InvAmnt PayAmnt
,orderId
from #payment
order by orderId
```

But this gives me a result, that only takes into account the last row and not the previous ones:

```
InvID   InvAmnt PayAmnt orderId
1       10,00   90,00   1
1       20,00   70,00   2
1       30,00   50,00   3
1       40,00   30,00   4
```

What happens here is that in the first row the new value is the original PayAmnt (100) minus InvAmnt(10) and it results in 90, which is correct. In the second row it subtracts InvAmnt (70) from the previous rows PayAmnt(100) minus InvAmnt(10). The resulting 70 is also correct. But in the next row it fails because the seconds row PayAmnt is not updated to 70 yet and the calculation is (100 - 20) - 30 which results in the wrong 50.
Any ideas, how this could be solved without iterative constructs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sum() windowing function as below:

```
Select *, PayAmnt = sum(InvAmnt) over() - Sum(InvAmnt) over(order by orderId)
     from #payment
     order by orderId
```

Comment: Perfect, thats it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try below one. It's like subtraction of PayAmnt and running total of invamt.

```
SELECT [InvID], [InvAmnt], [orderId],isnull([PayAmnt],0)-SUM(InvAmnt) OVER(ORDER BY [InvID]) as PayAmnt
FROM  #Table1
```